# How to determine whether USB C port supports video out?

Tags: windows, laptop, usb, video, usb-c

I was doing family tech support and a relative purchased a [dual screen extender](https://www.ofiyaa.net/) for an [Acer laptop](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.ABRAA.001) that he owns.

You can connect either extra screen via USB C cable or an HDMI plus USB for power.  The latter one works fine, but I can't get the USB C connection working at all.

In the course of doing research, [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-USB-C-capable-of-transmitting-video-from-a-laptop) article states that the USB C needs to explicitly support video output.

Which brings me to original question.  How can I determine whether or not this Acer laptop supports video of USB C?  I didn't see anything specific on Acer's website.

P.S. The OS is Windows 11.

Comment: Does your laptop have [this](https://us.answers.acer.com/euf/assets/images/answers/icons/usb-c_video.png) icon or [this](https://us.answers.acer.com/euf/assets/images/answers/icons/thunderbolt.png) icon near the USB port? According to the specifications of your device, it does not support DisplayPort which would be required to support video over Type-C 3.2 Gen 1.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I don't see either one of those icons.  What in the specs indicates that it doesn't support DisplayPort?  I am not sure what to look for.

Comment: The way I know it does not support DisplayPort is the fact, It does not indicate it supports DisplayPort.  It specifically only supports HDMI.  While Type-C alt mode does support HDMI it would have a logo on one of those ports if it did.